# Why isn't my if then statement running even though the condition is true?

Tags: lua, roblox

I was using an if then statement with the condition being if two values were equal.

```
local function hasPlayer(arr, val)
    for i, v in ipairs(arr) do
        print(val)
        print(v)
        if v == val then
            print("CODE WORKING")
        end
    end
end
```

The two variables that were printed showed the same thing, but it never printed "CODE WORKING".

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the two values I was comparing were instances, not values. I had to add ".name" to the end of "v" and "val".